# selectionChange not firing in Angular 7

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, typescript, angular7

I'm new to Angular(7+) and can't seem to get my `selectionChange` event to fire when I select a new value in my bootstrap-select dropdown.

Is there something I'm missing or some syntax I need?

I also tried (change), and (ngModelChange), but still nothing.
And no errors in the console...

Here is my HTML and component method

```js
  
import {BsDatepickerConfig} from 'ngx-bootstrap';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-register',
  templateUrl: './register.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./register.component.css']
})
export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {
  @Output() cancelRegister = new EventEmitter();
  user: User;
  registerForm: FormGroup;
  bsConfig: Partial < BsDatepickerConfig > ;
  emailErrorMessage: string;
  userErrorMessage: string;
  currentYear: number = new Date().getFullYear();
  startYear = this.currentYear - 120;
  years: number[] = [];
  months: string[] = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
  countryList = new Countries().countryCode;
  inputCity: string;


  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router,
    private alertify: AlertifyService, private fb: FormBuilder) {
    for (let i = this.currentYear; i > this.startYear; i--) {
      this.years.push(i);
    }
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.bsConfig = {
      containerClass: 'theme-red'
    };
    this.createRegisterForm();
  }

  onCountryChange(countryObj) {
    let test = 0;
  }

  onCityChange(cityObj) {
    let i = 0;
  }
 ...

}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <select (selectionChange)="onCountryChange($event)" id="country" class="form-control">
    <option *ngFor="let country of countryList" [value]="country.code" [selected]="country.name == 'United States'">
      {{country.name}}
    </option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: `(ngModelChange)` should be used to get the output on select element

Answer (score 3):

You could use `(change)="onCountryChange($event)"` instead

Answer (score 0):

Try (ngModelChange)="onCountryChange($event)"

Comment: There must be something else going on? I tried ngModelChange, but still nothing.